# cp: cannot stat 'install/netboot/*': No such file or directory

Tags: 16.04, pxe

I am trying to PXE boot my virtual machines (virtualbox) that are in my computer using the local host.

However, when I execute the following command:

```
$ sudo cp -fr install/netboot/* /var/lib/tftpboot/
 cp: cannot stat 'install/netboot/*': No such file or directory
```

I listed the content of the `install` directory but I didn't find the `netboot` directory. What did I miss?

I followed this guide:
https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-install-pxe-server-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Note: I have Ubuntu Desktop LTS 16

Answer (score 1):

No, the Desktop edition does not contains the required netboot files. You need to get either:

- Ubuntu server image (CD size: ~ 700MB)
- Pure Ubuntu netboot image from [cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/) (`mini.iso` < 60MB or `netboot.tar.gz` ~ 45MB)